# C++ Inheritance that throws a expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, c++11

I keep getting the following error and I am not sure why. After some googling I still do not have a solution. I included the files below so that hopefully you all can see something that I can't.

Error:

expected class-name before '{' token class LinkedList: public ListInterface{

LinkedList.h:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include "ListInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class LinkedList: public ListInterface {
   private:
   Node<T>* m_front;
   int m_length;

   void addFront(T entry) throw(std::runtime_error);
   void addBack(T entry);
   void removeFront() throw(std::runtime_error);
   void removeBack() throw(std::runtime_error);

 public:
  LinkedList();

  LinkedList(const LinkedList& original);

  ~LinkedList();
  LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& original);
  bool isEmpty() const;
  int getLength() const;
  void insert(int position, T entry) throw(std::runtime_error);
  void removeN(int position) throw(std::runtime_error);
  void clear();
  T getEntry(int position) const throw(std::runtime_error);
 void replace(int position, T newEntry) throw(std::runtime_error);
 };
#include "LinkedList.cpp"
#endif
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "ListInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
  m_length = 0;
  m_front = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList& original){
  if(original.m_front == nullptr){
    m_front = nullptr;
    return;
  }
  Node<T>* tempN = new Node<T>(original.getEntry(0));
  m_front = tempN;
  Node<T>* tempP = m_front;
  m_length = original.m_length;
  for(int i = 1; i < m_length; i++){
    tempN = nullptr;
    tempN = new Node<T>(original.getEntry(i));
    tempP->setNext(tempN);
    tempP = tempP->getNext();
  }
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
  clear();
  if(m_front != nullptr){
    delete m_front;
    m_front = nullptr;
  }
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator=(const LinkedList& original){
  if(original.m_front == nullptr){
    m_front = nullptr;
    return;
  }
  Node<T>* tempN = new Node<T>(original.getEntry(0));
  m_front = tempN;
  Node<T>* tempP = m_front;
  for(int i = 1; i < original.m_length(); i++){
    tempN = nullptr;
    tempN = new Node<T>(original.getEntry(i));
    tempP->setNext(tempN);
    tempP = tempP->getNext();
  }
}

template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() const{
  if(m_length == 0){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

template<typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::getLength() const{
  return m_length;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(int position, T entry) throw(std::runtime_error){
  Node<T>* temp = m_front;
  Node<T>* nTemp = nullptr;
  Node<T>* bTemp = m_front;
  if(position > m_length){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Invalid Position\n"));
  }else if(m_front == nullptr){
  //   throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Cannot insert into nonexistant list. Try addBack\n"));
    addBack(entry);
  }else{
    if(m_length == 0){
      // m_front = nTemp;
    }else{
      if(position == 0){
        // nTemp->setNext(m_front);
        // m_front = nTemp;
        addFront(entry);
      }else{
        nTemp = new Node<T>(entry);
        for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
          bTemp = bTemp->getNext();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < position - 1; i++){
          temp = temp->getNext();
        }
        temp->setNext(nTemp);
        nTemp->setNext(bTemp);
        m_length++;
      }
    }
  }
  temp = nullptr;
  nTemp = nullptr;
  bTemp = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeN(int position) throw(std::runtime_error){
  if(position == 0){
    try{
      removeFront();
    }catch(std::runtime_error e){}
  }else if(position == m_length - 1){
    try{
      removeBack();
    }catch(std::runtime_error e){};
  }else if(position < 0 || position >= m_length){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Invalid position"));
  }else{
    Node<T>* decon = m_front;
    Node<T>* preDecon = m_front;
    Node<T>* temp = m_front;
    for(int i = 0; i < position - 1; i++){
      preDecon = preDecon->getNext();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
      decon = decon->getNext();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < position + 1; i++){
      temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    preDecon->setNext(temp);
    decon->setNext(nullptr);
    delete decon;
    decon  = nullptr;
    preDecon = nullptr;
    temp = nullptr;
    m_length--;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
  while(m_length > 0){
    try{
      removeBack();
    }catch(std::runtime_error e){
      break;
    }
  }
  m_front = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getEntry(int position) const throw(std::runtime_error){
  if(position >= m_length){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Invalid position\n"));
  }
  Node<T>* temp = m_front;
  for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
    temp = temp->getNext();
  }
  return temp->getEntry();
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::replace(int position, T newEntry) throw(std::runtime_error){
  if(position >= m_length){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Invalid position\n"));
  }
  Node<T>* temp = m_front;
  for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
    temp = temp->getNext();
  }
  temp->setEntry(newEntry);
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFront(T entry) throw(std::runtime_error){
    if(m_front == nullptr){
      throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Cannot add to nonexistant list. Try addBack\n"));
    }
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(entry);
    temp->setNext(m_front);
    m_front = temp;
    m_length++;
    temp = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addBack(T entry){
  if(m_front == nullptr){
    m_front = new Node<T>(entry);
    m_length++;
  }else{
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(entry);
    Node<T>* mtemp = m_front;
    while(mtemp->getNext() != nullptr){
      mtemp = mtemp->getNext();
    }
    mtemp->setNext(temp);
    m_length++;
    temp = nullptr;
    delete temp;
    mtemp = nullptr;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeFront() throw(std::runtime_error){
  if(m_length == 0){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Nothing to remove"));
  }
  Node<T>* temp = m_front;
  m_front = temp->getNext();
  delete temp;
  temp = nullptr;
  m_length--;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeBack() throw(std::runtime_error){
  if(m_length <= 0){
    throw(std::runtime_error("ERROR: Nothing to remove"));
  }
  Node<T>* temp = m_front;
  for(int i = 0; i < m_length - 2; i++){
    temp = temp->getNext();
  }
  if(m_length == 1){
    delete temp;
    m_front = nullptr;
  }else{
    delete temp->getNext();
    temp->setNext(nullptr);
  }
  m_length--;
}
```

ListInterface:

```
#ifndef LIST_INTERFACE_H
#define LIST_INTERFACE_H

#include<stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class ListInterface
{
public:
/**
*   @pre None
*   @post Deletes a List
*   @return None
*/
virtual ~ListInterface(){}

/**
*   @pre None
*   @post Checks to see if the list has contents
*   @return None
*/
virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

/**
*   @pre None
*   @post Determines and returns list length
*   @return m_length
*/
virtual int getLength() const = 0;

/**
*   @pre 0<= position < m_length
*   @post Adds a new item to the list at the given position
*   @param position 0<= position < m_length
*   @param entry Valid type T
*   @throw std::runtime_error if position is invalid
*   @return None
*/
virtual void insert(int position, T entry) throw (std::runtime_error) = 0;

/**
*   @pre List must have items 0<= position < m_length
*   @post Removes an item from the list
*   @param position 0<=position< m_length
*   @throw std::runtime_error if position is invalid
*   @return None
*/
virtual void removeN(int position) throw (std::runtime_error) = 0;

/**
*   @pre List has items in it
*   @post Removes all list items
*   @return None
*/
virtual void clear() = 0;

/**
*   @pre Items exist in list 0<=position < m_length
*   @post Returns the value of an item in the list
*   @param position 0<=position < m_length
*   @throw std::runtime_error if position is invalid
*   @return Type T of entry
*/
virtual T getEntry(int position) const throw (std::runtime_error) = 0;

 /**
 *    @pre The position is between 1 and the list's length
 *    @post The entry at the given position is replaced with the new entry
 *    @param position:  0<= position <= length
 *    @param newEntry: A new entry to put in the list
 *    @throw std::runtime_error if the position is invalid.
 *    @return None
 */
 virtual void replace(int position, T newEntry) throw (std::runtime_error) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: The header file `LinkedList.h` includes `LinkedList.cpp` which includes `LinkedList.h` which includes `LinkedList.cpp` which includes... You don't see anything wrong with that? Do some research about *circular inclusion*.

Comment: If some "instructor" told you to do it  (include a cpp) that way with templates, tell them "no, that's ghetto and not professional". Learn to do it right. Better now than later. An excellent Q+A here: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: I missed copying the // comment notation for LinkedList.cpp. In LinkedList.cpp it does not include LinkedList.h because it is templated. That was left over from an older untemplated version.

Comment: Should obviously be ` ... : public ListInterface<T> {`. P.S. throw specifiers have been obsoleted in the modern C++ standard. If your instructor is telling you to use throw specifiers, find a more educated instructor. throw specifiers have really been botched, in general, in the C++ standard, but that's a different topic.

Comment: In case you missed what Sam first said, `public ListInterface` should be `public ListInterface<T>` in the inheritance chain of `class LinkedList`.

Comment: Then please *edit your question* to show the actual code (or preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also please  [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you to @SamVarshavchik for the answer. I apologize for breaking and StackOverflow question etiquette, I will try to learn it as I am new here.